# Can a repository be added to /etc/apt/sources.list using Ansible apt_repository?

Tags: ubuntu, ansible, apt

The [Ansible user manual](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/apt_repository_module.html) gives the following example to add repository:

```
- name: Add specified repository into sources list
  ansible.builtin.apt_repository:
    repo: deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal partner
    state: present
```

However, this adds the repo entry in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_canonical_com_ubuntu.list` rather than updating the default `/etc/apt/sources.list` file. As a result, Ubuntu does not show this repository in Software & Updates(see "Canonical Partners" checkbox below).

[image]

The user manual also indicates that `filename:` "Sets the name of the source list file in sources.list.d." However, this appears to only add entries in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` rather than the `/etc/apt/sources.list` file.

**Is it possible to use `ansible.builtin.apt_repository` to add repo entries to `/etc/apt/sources.list` (i.e., rather than using template or lineinfile)?**

Comment: Not sure why this question was down voted and closed for being a "general computing hardware and software" question. It is a well researched question clearly directed to a problem related to the proper use of a common software module that is not well documented elsewhere.

Comment: It was likely closed because it's posted on the wrong Stack Exchange site. Stack Overflow is for programming and software development questions. Ansible is a system administration and configuration tool, so a more appropriate forum for your question would be Super User, Unix & Linux, or Server Fault. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic for a list of what topics are appropriate for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your question

> Is it possible to use `ansible.builtin.apt_repository` to add repo entries to `/etc/apt/sources.list`

it seems to be not according

- Documentation [`apt_repository` Parameter: `filename`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/apt_repository_module.html#parameter-filename)
- Current source code of [`ansible/modules/apt_repository.py`](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/modules/apt_repository.py)
- The behavior you described "*... this appears to only add entries in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`...*"

It is the intended behavior as it has less complexity and [`this approach is simpler`](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/modules/apt_repository.py#L191) than changing or editing existing files.

Your mentioned approach with

> ... using `template` or `lineinfile`

would add probably unnecessary complexity.

**Further Q&A**

- [`sources.list.d` vs. `sources.list`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22968952/)
- [What is the function of `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26020917/)
- [What is the benefit of `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` over `/etc/apt/sources.list`?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/407328/)

Comment: Agreed, template/lineinfile may not be as elegant but it has the advantage of displaying the correct information for repos picked up by the ubuntu gui.